# app compact v7 is not work on androidx so how to make this project in new library

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx

```
===== Error ======

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.milesstudio.photoeditor, PID: 19734
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.milesstudio.photoeditor/com.milesstudio.photoeditor.Collage_Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #76: Binary XML file line #76: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3430)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #76: Binary XML file line #76: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #76: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.milesstudio.photoeditor-u_XgTUf7zqGb5Ukgt5P1JQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.milesstudio.photoeditor-u_XgTUf7zqGb5Ukgt5P1JQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.milesstudio.photoeditor-u_XgTUf7zqGb5Ukgt5P1JQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:801)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:874)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:498)
        at com.android.internal.policy.HwPhoneWindow.setContentView(HwPhoneWindow.java:342)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2941)
        at com.milesstudio.photoeditor.Collage_Activity.onCreate(Collage_Activity.java:1584)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7458)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7448)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19734 SIG: 9
Process 19734 terminated.
```

Comment: add below in your gradle 
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
and

import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout

Answer (score 1):

You need to use compatible AndroidX library.

For `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` use material dependency with:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

then change the view to:

```
com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
```

See:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings.

Comment: now generate a new error  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #87: Binary XML file line #87: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #87: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

Comment: You need to change all the view from support libraries to AndroidX. For that error, change it to `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout`. You can change it manually by removing the view name then retype the view last name. Auto-complete feature in Android Studio will suggest you some relevant views.

Comment: Process: com.milesstudio.photoeditor, PID: 7369
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.milesstudio.photoeditor/com.milesstudio.photoeditor.Collage_Activity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: @DevinPatel now update question with new error logs you are getting